# Where will i get Magento( 1.9 ) Project base Tutorial for beginner?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, learn-magento

I know php. Now i want to learn Magento( 1.9 version) top to bottom. But I did not find any believable source which i can follow and go ahead step by step. I need suggestions. How can i get started with Magento 1.9 ? Where will I find project base tutorial which is for a actual beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn magento from many blogs. You need to first downalod magento from [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download) and then you have to setup to start. you can learn by practice. below are some source of tutorial.

There is good source available for learn magento basics.You can start from good source available by magento : http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html. And Technical document : https://magento.com/resources/technical And MagentoU offer some free and paid course and video tutorials :https://u.magento.com/

There is some good blog available at siteground:https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/

Also at Magestore : http://blog.magestore.com/magento-training/magento-tutorials/

For advance, how to create custom module. You can use module creators.

Hope this will help!